# Adding elements to cascade ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I have the following List to keep 3x3 matrix values:

```
1 2 3 
4 5 6
7 8 9

List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

I want to add matrix values as shown below:

```
list.add(0, new ArrayList<Integer>{1, 2, 3});
list.add(1, new ArrayList<Integer>{4, 5, 6});
list.add(2, new ArrayList<Integer>{7, 8, 9});
```

But encounter syntax error. So, is it the correct way, or what is the proper way to assign matrix values by using cascade list?

Comment: Delete "0, ", "1, ", "2, " and it works. Or you want to use Dictionary<int, List<Integer>> instead? Or was it not Dictionary in Java, something else?

Comment: Would a multidimensional array be more suitable?

Comment: @BitLauncher I tried before asking the question, but did not worked. Do you mean `list.add(new ArrayList<Integer>{1,2,3});`? I used like that. Any idea?

Comment: @Sid You right, but it is a question and I have to use List :( Any idea?

Comment: @Eklavya Why did you delete your post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the following options:

1. **Java-9 onwards:**

   ```
   List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
   list.add(List.of(1, 2, 3));
   list.add(List.of(4, 5, 6));
   list.add(List.of(7, 8, 9));
   ```
2. **Before Java-9:**

   ```
   List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
   list.add(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
   list.add(Arrays.asList(4, 5, 6));
   list.add(Arrays.asList(7, 8, 9));
   ```
3. **`List` of `Integer[]`**

   ```
       List<Integer[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
       list.add(new Integer[] { 1, 2, 3 });
       list.add(new Integer[] { 4, 5, 6 });
       list.add(new Integer[] { 7, 8, 9 });
   ```
4. **Using Stream API:**

   ```
        List<List<Integer>> list = Stream.of(
                                            List.of(1, 2, 3), 
                                            List.of(4, 5, 6), 
                                            List.of(7, 8, 9))
                                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
   ```

Comment: Nice answer.  On the last one, you might want to do a `map(ArrayList::new)` since `List.of` is immutable.  The OP may want to manipulate the values.

Answer (score 2):

There is no short form syntax to create an ArrayList and add items to it such as `new ArrayList<Integer>{1, 2, 3}`.

If you don't need to ArrayList, I would recommend using the immutable lists created by the `List.of` method:

```
list.add(0, List.of(1, 2, 3));
list.add(1, List.of(4, 5, 6));
list.add(2, List.of(7, 8, 9));
```

If you must use ArrayList for some reason, do it like this:

```
List<Integer> arrayList0 = new ArrayList<>();
arrayList0.add(1);
arrayList0.add(2);
arrayList0.add(3);

list.add(0, arrayList0);

// repeat for index 1, 2
```

Comment: Maybe better to mention `List.of` is available from Java 9

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly specify the element to add in the `ArrayList` constructor. Instead, you can do this.

```
List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(0, List.of(1, 2, 3));
list.add(1, List.of(4, 5, 6));
list.add(2, List.of(7, 8, 9));
```

Or

```
List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(0, Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
list.add(1, Arrays.asList(4, 5, 6));
list.add(2, Arrays.asList(7, 8, 9));
```

Note that `List.of` returns an immutable list. And `Arrays.asList` returns a list that can be `set` but not `add`.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

```
    list.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3)));
    list.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(4, 5, 6)));
    list.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(7, 8, 9)));
```

Option 2:

```
    List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> subList;
    int n = 1;

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
        subList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j){
            subList.add(n);
            n++;
        }
        list.add(subList);
    }
```

Comment: Welcome :) glad that it was helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can't initialize a java ArrayList like that.
You can do it in the following ways:

1. use `Arrays.asList`

   new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
2. if you use guava

   Lists.newArrayList(1, 2, 3)
3. if you use Java8

   Stream.of(1, 2, 3).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new))

Answer (score 0):

That's another solution, a bit complex but it works:

```
    List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer>row1 = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList<Integer>row2 = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList<Integer>row3 = new ArrayList();
    row1.addAll(List.of(1, 2, 3));
    row2.addAll(List.of(4, 5, 6));
    row3.addAll(List.of(7, 8, 9));
    
    list.add(0,row1);
    list.add(1,row2);
    list.add(2,row3);

    System.out.println(list);
```